# Not in scope: <*>

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I was trying out some of the examples in the [A Fistful of Monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) chapter of *Learn you a Haskell*, and some returned errors when I ran them in GHCi 7.6.3:

```
Prelude> Just (+3) <*> Just 3

<interactive>:2:11: Not in scope: `<*>'
```

I get a similar error when using `<$>`.

Comment: You need to `import Control.Applicative`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These operators are from [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html). You need to `import Control.Applicative` or say `:m +Control.Applicative` in `ghci`. You can find out where many standard operators come from using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%24%3E).

As of GHC 7.10, with the [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) implemented in [`base` 4.8](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0), `<*>` is now present in the Prelude and does not require an import.